# How do I automate importing repos in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

How do I automate cloning/pushing certain repos to a gitlab instance when it is instantiated?

I'm building an IaC project which uses Gitlab, Terraform and Docker to build testing lab pods.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With [Gitlab provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gitlabhq/gitlab/latest/docs/resources/project):

```
resource "gitlab_project" "terraform" {
  name = "my_shiny_new_project"
  import_url = "https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform.git"
}
```

Above will create a new project named "terraform" containing cloned repo from given URL.